# Can a finite set in $R^n$ be open in the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology

I have so far only the definition of a topology and the standard topology $\tau$ on $R^d$. I'm a self-learning beginner, so sorry if my question is overly wordy. I'm confusing myself because everything is now more general than it was back in metric spaces. I know that in the standard topology, a singleton set is not open, because you won't be able to find an r > 0 and still have $B_r(p) \subset {p}$.

But what about for 2 points? For example, for the standard topology with $M = R^d$, I'm testing whether or not the set U = {a,b} will be in $\tau$. And then naturally, what about a finite set?

My attempt was to say that for point a, I could always take r between a and b, s.t. (Euclidean) $d(a,r) < d(a, b)$. Then since $a$ would be the only point in the ball, and $a \in U$, then we would satisfy the definition of open in the standard topology. Similarly for b.

Unfortunately I feel like I'm missing something simple, and so: can finite sets in $R^d$ be open in the standard topology? Thanks very much.

Comment: Every $B_r(p)$ is an infinite set.

Comment: Could someone please explain why all balls are infinite sets? I thought that a ball was simply the set of all points that lie within a certain radius of the center point p. Thus, can't you have a ball that contains of just a single point? From below, my thinking that in the 2 element set case, you would end up with $B_r(a) = {a}$ choosing $r$ to not include $b$, but from the below answers, something is obviously wrong with that logic.

Comment: I'll try again: every ball $B_r(p)$ (with $r>0$) **in $\Bbb R^n$** (with $n\ge1$) is an infinite set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach going from 2 elements to finitely many elements is a good way of thinking about it. Suppose that some finite set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is open. Since your set is finite, it's not hard to show that if you take an open ball around some $a\in A$ containing another point $b\in A$, then you can assume without loss of generality that $a,b$ are the only two points lying in the intersection of $A$ and this open ball (otherwise you could just remove some open balls and still end up with an open neighborhood, which is all we need). We know that the intersection of two open sets, our open neighborhood and $A$, must be open, but a set of two elements cannot be open (hopefully you reached this conclusion when you were trying to solve this case). Therefore, our original assumption that $A$ was finite cannot be true.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response; I understood that. (Although I am still trying to convince myself that a set of 2 elements can be open, but if I assume that, everything else does follow.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the empty set. This is finite and open.

However, if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a non-empty open set, then $U$ cannot be finite in the standard topology. To see why this is true, if $v \in U,$ then there is an open ball $B_r(v)$ such that $B_r(v) \subset U,$ because $U$ is open. Since $B_r(v)$ is an infinite subset of $U,$ then $U$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

No, they cannot. For convenience, let's take the finite set $\{a,b\}\subset \mathbb{R}$. We'll show that the complement $U$ of $\{a,b\}$ is an open subset (and thus $\{a,b\}$ is closed). Take $x\in U$. Let $\delta=\min \{|x-a|,|x-b|\}$. Then $(x-\delta/2,x+\delta/2)\subset U$. We conclude that $U$ is an open subset, and thus $\{a,b\}$ is closed. Do you see how to generalize?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see that it is closed as you said, but closed does not imply not open.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected, so the only non-empty subset that is both open and closed is $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself.